# Display first oembed only wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, oembed

I am trying to create a function for the video and audio post format to display only the first oembed media in the content.

I was able to figure out how to create the content filter and have the function only apply to video and audio post format.

```
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'first_oembed_only', 8 );
function first_oembed_only($content) { 
  if(has_post_format(array('video','audio'))) {
    //show first oembed only
    //if other media and oembeds exist remove
    //make a div with the remaining content that only allows text and images
  return $content;
  }
}
```

Another task the function needs to do is also remove any oembeds or media except images then contain in a div.

I found that I can use preg match to find [embed] and [video] shortcodes and / but can I also do that with css right or would that be the best option?

example:

```
.single-format-video iframe
.single-format-video video {
 display: none;
}
```

The most tricky part for me is how will I wrap the div around the content excluding the first oembed?